# styling in react native

Tags: css, user-interface, react-native, styles

I am involved in a project that several people working on a react native project.

I need to find a way to separate the styling tasks form code, in a way that UI develop can work without the need of code developer (from my point of view, a style is a person who define the structure of UI, place components on screen and also define their color and visual representation).

my questions are:

- Is there any tools that the style developer can use to create styles and export suitable files for inclusion to  project?
- How can I make sure that the two team work without duplicating their work by other team? I came from a WPF and Web development, and in that systems, there is a good separation between the UI and codes. For example, In MVVM, the only agreement that stylist and coder should have is the name of component, and the stylist can make all of the styles and coder can do all of the coding without repeating their work (I know that this is over simplified, but the concept is there and a good team can use it). In a web development, stylist create the HTML and CSS, and the coder use angolarJS or JQuery to control the component and attach to their events.
- In our styling team we are using skitch, can this tool generate suitable style code for react native? If yes, what would be the workflow?
- Any other suggestion on how best to separate styling from coding in react native.

Comment: There are tools like BuilderX.io that aim to do this. Posting this as a comment instead of answer, because I haven't really used in and can't recommend it out of experience.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the best answer for this question, But I can provide you some feedback & tips from my experience.

For separating UI & Business code like in MVVM, you can separate the classes as

1. **Container** class (handles all business logic) and
2. **View** class (Only responsible for presentation) with styles defined as a separate class that can make use of some **universal theme provider**

There can be multiple view classes (iOs, Android , if possible Web) but all them will use the main container class for business logic (REfer 1st link for more details)

Refer:

- https://blog.cloudboost.io/react-native-a-deep-dive-part-1-5a982f847d20
- https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

For styling you can opt for some Theme Provider classes that will hold universal themes as an object. The coder can use these styles in the components. The main theme will be defined in the root class with the provider. If you are carefully reusing these styles, you only need to update the styles in one place updating all of them. Also there is support for dark & light themes.

Refer:

- https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper
- https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit
- https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui